# How to get $p$ in this equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\dfrac{p}{p+3}=\dfrac{2p-1}{2p}$$

Get $p$. How can one solve these type of questions? What is the easiest and quickest method?

Comment: What's wrong with $2p^2=(2p-1)(p+3)$? Of course under the conditions $p \neq 0$ and $p+3 \neq 0$. From a geometrical point of view, you are looking for the intersection points of two hyperbolas, and it is natural that you should solve a second order equation.

Comment: You've gotten answers, but generally, you want to simplify in an efficient way that produces correct results. For ratio problems like this, the typical approach is cross multiply, simplify, gather like terms and then solve resulting problem.

Answer (score 7):

The given equation is

$$\frac{p}{p+3}=\frac{2p-1}{2p}$$

Equation is solving if $p\neq 0$ and $p+3\neq 0\implies p\neq -3$
$$\begin{align*}
p\cdot 2p&=(2p-1)(p+3)\\
2p^2&=(2p-1)(p+3)\\
2p^2&=2p^2-p+6p-3\\
2p^2&=2p^2+5p-3\\
2p^2-2p^2&=5p-3\\
3&=5p\\
p&=\frac{3}{5}
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thank you sir! And how would one solve a similar equation for example: $ \dfrac{p-1}{q} =  \dfrac{q-1}{2p-1} = \dfrac{3}{5} $ I am guessing $ (p-1)(2p-1) = q(q-1) - \dfrac{3}{5} $  Is this correct?

Comment: @kamal This is actually two equations. $\frac{p-1}{q}=\frac{3}{5}$ and $\frac{q-1}{2p-1}=\frac{3}{5}$.

Comment: So would you have to solve this: $(p-1)5 - 3q = (q-1)5 - (2p-1)3 $  Or is this again incorrect?

Comment: @kamal As Patrick has pointed out, you have two equations in p and q. To solve them, use the first:
$\frac{p-1}{q}=\frac{3}{5} \implies p=\frac{3}{5}q+1$
We may substitute this into our second equation, to give:
$\frac{q-1}{2p-1}=\frac{3}{5} \implies \frac{q-1}{\frac{6}{5}q+2-1}=\frac{q-1}{\frac{6}{5}q+1}=\frac{3}{5}$
Thus
$q-1=\frac{18}{25}q+\frac{3}{5}$
And finally
$\frac{7}{25}q=\frac{8}{5} \implies q=\frac{40}{7}$
Substituting into our first equation, 
$p=\frac{3}{5}\frac{40}{7}+1=\frac{31}{7}$

Answer (score 0):

You can deal with it as following:

$$\frac{p}{p+3}=\frac{2p-1}{2p}\Rightarrow 1-\frac{p}{p+3}=1-\frac{2p-1}{2p}\Rightarrow \frac{3}{p+3}=\frac{1}{2p}\Rightarrow 6p=p+3\Rightarrow p=\frac{3}{5}$$

Answer (score 0):

The *easiest* and *quickest* method is by "**componendo / divideno**". [See Hall and Knight.]

From the original equation, we do $\dfrac {p - (p + 3)} {p + 3} = \dfrac {2p - 1 - (2p)} {2p}$

Therefore,  $\dfrac {- 3} {p + 3} = \dfrac {- 1} {2p}$

Then, $6p = p + 3$, and hence the result.

Answer (score 0):

The most common way of solving such equations is through cross multiplication which states that if : $\dfrac{a}{b}$ =  $\dfrac{c}{d}$ , then: *ad = bc*

Instead of proceeding with this, we will work around in a slightly different way which will significantly reduce our calculation:

Provided:

$\dfrac{p}{p+3}$ =  $\dfrac{2p-1}{2p}$

Subtracting 1 from both sides:

$\dfrac{-3}{p+3}$ =  $\dfrac{-1}{2p}$  [Ignoring basic steps]

Now, we cross multiply (after multiplying both sides by -1):

3(2p) = p+3

= 6p = p + 3

Subtracting 'p' from both sides:

5p = 3

Dividing both sides by 5 :

p = $\dfrac{3}{5}$